# %random% in batch and how to avoid specific numbers within a specific range?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to preform a task in batch that generates random numbers in a specific range which I have already done using the code listed below.

```
set /a setvar=%random% %% 100+0
```

Additionally a set of numbers should be also avoided which I could not implement by myself up to now.

What I mean is a batch file that would generate numbers between 1-100 but avoid the numbers 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 and 90.

Is there any solution for this? I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: set list of values that should be avoided
for /l %%N in (10,10,90) do (
    set "_%%N=."
)


    set /a setvar=%random% %% 100+1
    :: if value is in the list sums the set value with 
    :: random value between 0 and 9 getting modulus of 9 
    if defined _%setvar% (
        set /a setvar=setvar +  %random% %% 9 + 1
    )


echo %setvar%
```

Comment: Good, but would be better with some comments :-)

Comment: @Mofi ,@jeb - I've added comments.And is possible to hit a case when modulus of 9 is null at the same time when the value is fold of 10 .Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:GetNumber
set /a setvar=%random% %% 100 + 1
IF %setvar% neq 100 IF %setvar:~-1%==0 GOTO getnumber
echo Random number is %setvar%

GOTO :EOF
```

You say you don't want to produce ?0 but you did not say you did not want `100`. This procedure generates without (10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90). If you also want to exclude 100, then remove the `IF %setvar% neq 100`

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to achieve:

```
@echo off
:GetNumber
set /a Number=%random% %% 100
set /a Remainder=Number %% 10
if %Remainder% == 9 if not %Number% == 99 goto GetNumber
set /a Number+=1
echo Random number is %Number%
```

First a random number is calculated in range 0 to 99 by dividing a random number by 100 and assigned just the remainder to the environment variable.

This random number is divided by 10 to get the remainder.

If this remainder is 9 and the number is not 99, the number would be 10, or 20, or 30, ... after adding 1 in last step. Therefore the numbers 9, 19, 29, 39, ... must be ignored by run the entire calculation once more with a new random number.

Answer (score 1):

For a value in the range 1-99, just ensure the last digit fall in the 1-9 range

```
set /a "setvar=(%random% %% 100 / 10 * 10) + (%random% %% 9 + 1)"
```

Alternatively, if the range is 1-100 and the 100 must be included in the list of allowed values

```
set /a "x=%random% %% 91 + 1", "x=x+(x-1)/9", "x=x-x/100"
```

In this case, the source range `1-91` (that is `1-100` except the problematic numbers) is mapped to the target range `1-100` adding the adecuated values to skip the excluded numbers